# Resigning and leaving SE

Tags: discussion

I am stepping down as moderator and leaving the SE system. I have given a more detailed explanation at the other site I moderate

https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/resigning-and-leaving-se

Answer (score 5):

### Thank you for your service.  You will be missed.

Considering what is going on at Stack Exchange Inc., we entirely understand your decision.  I'm sure I will speak for many of us when I say we will miss you and your contributions as a user and moderator.  This is a sad day for our community.

Take care!

Answer (score 3):

Can't really say anything more than what gerrit said. Thanks for helping this site prosper and you will be definitely missed. I secretly also hope the direction of SE will reverse at some point and we can welcome you back again.